# I can't access GLM

Tags: c++, glm-math

I downloaded GLM from the site. First of all, I can't unzip the file, as it didn't come in .zip format. I used a zip unarchiver and it still did not produce an unzipped file. Regardless, I tried including a header search path but Xcode has this weird Debug/Release path. Don't know which to access, but I tried putting the path to the glm files on both Debug and Release. Still did not let me use glm files. Lastly, I tried putting the glm files directly into the project files, and it still did not let me use the files in glm.

I looked at other posts on stack for the same problem, and they all said to include it into the header search path, but their format is different from mine. Idk, just need some really clear directions on this as everything is out of order.

Comment: You'll need to post your actual information and not just a description of it. What do you mean when you say, "I tried including a header search path but Xcode has this weird Debug/Release path"? Xcode has header search paths. If you want you can make them different between Debug and Release, but they aren't by default. When you say, "Still did not let me use glm files," what do you mean? Did you get an error? If so, please post the exact text of the error. Please post as much information as possible.

Comment: If it is not a zip file, what is it instead? How did you get the glm headers from that single file, if you don’t know what it is? What was the link to download that file?